# separation of layers when performing CRUD operations

Tags: c#, .net, json, visual-studio, odata

I am confused on where my deserialization logic should go.

I have a controller that returns data to the client **specifically for a GET operation:**

```
public accountscontroller:apicontroller
{
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("", Name = "GetAccount")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAccount()
        {
            var query = Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery.Split('/')[2];
            var response = await _accountService.GetAccount(query);

            if (response == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(response);
        }
//morestuff
}
```

and the `AccountService.GetAccount` code is the following:

```
public class AccountService
{
        public async Task<Account> GetAccount(string query)
        {
            var task = await Client.HTTPCLIENT.GetAsync(Client.HTTPCLIENT.BaseAddress + query);
            var jsonString = await task.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
            return value.value.FirstOrDefault();
        }
//morestuff
}
```

as you can see, the deserialization is handled in the `AccountService`, not the `AccountsController`

however, if we look at the **POST operation:**

```
public class AccountController
{
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("", Name = "CreateAccount")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateAccount([FromBody] JObject account)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var response = await _accountService.Create(account);

            var newAccount = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();

            return Ok(newAccount);
}
```

and the underlying Create method within the `AccountService`:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Create(JObject account)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Client.HTTPCLIENT.BaseAddress + "accounts")
        {
            Content = new StringContent(account.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };

        var response = await Client.HTTPCLIENT.SendAsync(request);
        var uri = new Uri(response.Headers.GetValues("OData-EntityId").FirstOrDefault());
        return await Client.HTTPCLIENT.GetAsync(uri);
    }
```

you will see that in fact the deserialization happens on the *controller* level.

**How can I encapsulate the deserialization logic for CRUD operations, such as GET/PUT/POST for consistency?**

Comment: you abstract it behind a injectable service. The second code snippet is using an extension method for http content which under the hood is also using Json.Net. You are mixing concerns.

Comment: If you were accessing the data directly you wouldn't have to deserialize the data, right? But since you are accessing a second api and receiving a json AND you seem to want only part of the information "return value.value.FirstOrDefault();", then I think it makes sense to hide that logic in your service and not leave it on the controller.